# How to compile intel icpc with zlib mmic

Tags: xeon-phi, icc

I have compile zlib for Xeon Phi using flag mmic because in the next instruction

```
icpc -I. -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wall -Wno-parentheses -Wextra -O3 -D NDEBUG -g -c -o build/release/minisat/simp/Main.o minisat/simp/Main.cc -MMD -MF build/release/minisat/simp/Main.d -mmic
```

I get

```
catastrophic error: cannot open source file "zlib.h"
```

The compiled zlib with mmic library is in the folder /path/zlib/. My question is how to add that path to avoid the error?. I trying -L/path/zlib -lz but I get the same error.

Comment: Run find /path -name zlib.h to see if the header is really where you think it is.

Comment: As @Jeff said, run `find /path -name zlib.h` to locate the file `zlib.h` (where `/path` is the path you mentioned in your question). Then, assuming the `find` command returns you something like `/path/zlib/include/zlib.h`, add `-I/path/zlib/include` to your compiler command line. And likely, for link time, you'll have to add `-L/path/zlib/lib` or something similar...